# Left-align text when converting from md to pdf

Tags: pandoc

I'm converting a markdown file to pdf with:

```
pandoc -o out.pdf in.md
```

The results are justified alignment, a pet hate. Is there any way to render regular text as left-aligned instead?  Nothing appears in help for 'left' or 'align'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the latex package `ragged2e`.

### For one document

Add this to your yaml front matter:

```
---
header-includes: 
- \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
---
```

### For all documents

Edit your pandoc latex template; to create it:

```
pandoc -D latex > ~/.pandoc/templates/default.latex
```

Then open the file and add somewhere before the `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

Comment: The first method works, thanks. But for some reason the global method has no effect for me.

Comment: @geotheory sorry, there were typos in the path to the template; I fixed them.